# Boost Regex Giving Blank Capture

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to match strings of the form *XXX >|<|>=|<=|== YYY*, using the boost regex library. My code below shows that I am trying to match "x.y<123". However, the captures are "x.y", " ", "123", instead of "x.y", "<", "123". Anyone knows why?

```
boost::regex e("(.+?) *(>=|<=|==|>|<) *(.+)");
boost::smatch what;
if (boost::regex_match(std::string("x.y<123"), what, e)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < what.size(); ++ i)
        std::cout << std::string(what[i]) << std::endl;
}
else
    std::cout << "Fail matching" << std::endl;
```

Comment: You regex looks ok, but have you play with the last argument of the match function `match_flag_type` the default behavior may explain why you don't get "<" !

Comment: @alexbuisson: I obtain the same result with the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The match results refer back to the string being searched. Since yours is a temporary, the results are undefined.

```
if (boost::regex_match(std::string("x.y<123"), what, e)) { // bad


std::string s("x.y<123");
if (boost::regex_match(s, what, e)) { // good
```

Comment: +1, better than the conspiracy of the metacharacters :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I hate regex syntax. Never remember what `(` and `\(` mean in the flavour of the month.